# Hadoop data join package

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to hadoop while exploring the hadoop data join package I am given the below mentioned command:

```
hadoop jar /home/biadmin/DataJoin.jar com.datajoin.DataJoin 
         /user/biadmin/Datajoin/customers.txt 
         /user/biadmin/Datajoin/orders.txt 
         /user/biadmin/Datajoin/outpu1
```

I am getting below error Exception in thread `main`

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.hadoop.contrib.utils.join.DataJoinMapperBase
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:364)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:154)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:777)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$400(URLClassLoader.java:96)
```

Comment: possibly  `hadoop-datajoin` package is not in classpath.

Comment: The image did not upload correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [**`hadoop-datajoin`**](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-datajoin/2.7.0) jar into classpath while running the job. Use the `-libjars` option for adding the extra jars into class path. Your command will be like this. Provide the correct path to jar directory or you can download the jars.

```
hadoop jar /home/biadmin/DataJoin.jar com.datajoin.DataJoin 
     -libjars <path>/hadoop-datajoin.jar
     /user/biadmin/Datajoin/customers.txt 
     /user/biadmin/Datajoin/orders.txt 
     /user/biadmin/Datajoin/outpu1
```

Comment: After giving the Hadoop-DataJoin.jar path i am getting the same error. but when i ran the whole program in debug mode means giving the input paths in program the whole program ran correctly but while giving command through command line in map reduce mode it is throwing an no class defination found error.please suggest.

Comment: biadmin@bivm:~> hadoop jar /home/biadmin/DataJoin.jar com.datajoin.DataJoin -libjars /home/biadmin/eclipse/plugins/com.ibm.hadoop_2.2.0.v20141110_1927/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-datajoin-2.2.0.jar /user/biadmin/Datajoin/customers.txt /user/biadmin/Datajoin/orders.txt /user/biadmin/Datajoin/output1

Comment: @AshishSingh instead of referring from eclipse plugins, can you download a new jar and try with that.

Comment: Still it is giving the same error @Young i have tried with diffrenet version of data join package i am using the IBM Big Insight.

Comment: @AshishSingh can you try with this option adding in your command. `-D mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true`. This is to give preference to user path then hadoop path.